# GroupBy Extension Usage on Array on Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, closures

I have an array consists of Dictionary.

I need to group them by Key in a dictionary.

I tried the line, but do not know what to write in handler. I am trying

globalArray.groupBy(handler: {$0["Name"]})

it gives error;

Cannot convert value of type "String?" to closure result type "_"

my group by extension is as follows;

```
extension Sequence {
// Using a `typealias` because it's shorter to write `E`
// Think of it as a shortcut
typealias E = Iterator.Element

// Declaring a `K` generic that we'll use as the type of the key
// for the resulting dictionary. The only restriction is having
// it conforming to the `Hashable` protocol
func groupBy<K: Hashable>(handler: (E) -> K) -> [K: [E]] {
    // Creating the resulting dictionary
    var grouped = [K: [E]]()

    // Iterating over our elements
    self.forEach { item in
        // Retrieving the key based on the current item
        let key = handler(item)

        if grouped[key] == nil {
            grouped[key] = []
        }
        grouped[key]?.append(item)
    }

    return grouped
}
```

}

Could you please show me the right usage?

BR,

Erdem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this  `extension` to group array , and it is working superbly

```
extension Array {
    func grouped<T>(by criteria: (Element) -> T) -> [T: [Element]] {
        var groups = [T: [Element]]()
        for element in self {
            let key = criteria(element)
            if groups.keys.contains(key) == false {
                groups[key] = [Element]()
            }
            groups[key]?.append(element)
        }
        return groups
    }
}
```

How I use

```
array.grouped { (object:MyObjectClass) -> String in
        return object.location?.name ?? "EmptyKey"
        //Here you need to return your key 
    }
```

Hope it is helpful to you